# How to update text field value based on comparision with dropdown value in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-1.5, angularjs-1.6

Hi I am new to Angular JS.
I have one HTML file which has one dropdown and one textarea. Text area value will be updated based on selected dropdown value. **Note here: textarea won't display the same value which is selected by user in dropdown. It will display some other value based on dropdown's value.**

Below is my HTML code snippet. Dropdown's value are coming from backend which I got after making rest call in my controller:

```
   <select name="functionality" id="functionality" ng-model="selectedFunctionality">
       <option ng-repeat="functionality in functionalities.menuDetailsList.menuDetails" value="{{functionality.menuName}}">{{functionality.menuName}}</option>
   </select>

   <textarea id="scode" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFunctionality"></textarea>
```

Response which I am getting from backend is like this in XML format:

```
<menuDetailsList>
    <menuDetails>
        <menuName>FIRST</menuName>
        <taskList>
            <task>HYNN911</task>
            <task>HXTELE</task>
            <task>HXBTBCT</task>
        </taskList>
    </menuDetails>
    <menuDetails>
        <menuName>SECOND</menuName>
        <taskList>
            <task>1234</task>
            <task>abcd</task>
            <task>efghi</task>
        </taskList>
    </menuDetails> 
<menuDetailsList>
```

In dropdownlist, I am displaying "menuName" as you can see in XML response. While in textarea I need to display corresponding tasklist.I have used "ng-model" in my HTML code, but that gives the value of selected menu. But I need to get corresponding tasks value. How can we do this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I converted your xml into a json object but the rest is same. Using `$filter` you can achieve it. Here how you can do it. First you have to dependency inject `$filter` then start using it. Since you have multiple taks for each menuName so i displayed all of them.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.msg = "Hello";
  
  $scope.menuDetailsList = [
      {
        "menuName": "FIRST",
        "taskList": {
          "task": [
            "HYNN911",
            "HXTELE",
            "HXBTBCT"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "menuName": "SECOND",
        "taskList": {
          "task": [
            "1234",
            "abcd",
            "efghi"
          ]
        }
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.$watch('selectedFunctionality', function (newV, oldV) {
      if (newV != oldV) {
        if(angular.isDefined($scope.menuDetailsList)) {
          var matchedMenu = $filter('filter')($scope.menuDetailsList, {menuName: $scope.selectedFunctionality});
          debugger;
          if (matchedMenu.length !=0 ) {
            $scope.tasks = matchedMenu[0].taskList.task;
          }
          
        }
      }
    });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="container" ng-controller="MainController" style="margin-top:20px;">
    
    <div class="row">
      <label for="functionality">Select an item</label>
    <select name="functionality" id="functionality" ng-model="selectedFunctionality">
       <option ng-repeat="functionality in menuDetailsList" value="{{functionality.menuName}}">{{functionality.menuName}}</option>
   </select>
   </div>
  <br />
  <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <textarea id="scode" class="form-control" ng-model="task"></textarea>
   <br />
   </div>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```